# Couchdb: filter from the right of an array with endkey

Tags: couchdb

Say I have the following keys:

```
[1,0,"foo"]
[2,1,"foo"]
[3,3,"foo"]
[4,0,"foo"]
[5,1,"bar"]
[6,0,"bar"]
[7,1,"bazz"]
[8,1,"bazz"]
```

What I want is filter all keys that don't end with `"bar"` (ie: only keep `"bar"` keys)

I tried with `endkey=["bar"]` without success...

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "end with". The ending is the third element of key array or the suffix of the third element?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a new index in with a different key, e.g.:

```
["foo",1,0]
["foo",2,1]
["foo",3,3]
["foo",4,0]
["bar",5,1]
["bar",6,0]
["bazz",7,1]
["bazz",8,1]
```

... or just:

```
"foo"
"foo"
"foo"
"foo"
"bar"
"bar"
"bazz"
"bazz"
```

An index is just sorted in 1 way, so there's no other way to do what you want efficiently.